# Posting form from one iframe to another - IE

Tags: javascript, forms, internet-explorer, iframe, window

This appears to be an age old problem. But I can't seem to find a solution to it.

I have a page with two iframes on it. They are loading as such:

```
<iframe id="leftIframe" src="predict_goalkeepers.php" height="900" width="300" frameBorder="0" hspace="0"></iframe> <iframe id="rightIframe" src="predict_right.php" height="900" width="300" frameBorder="0" hspace="0"></iframe>
```

I then want to post something from the leftIframe to the right and refresh the leftIframe at the same time. This I have done through target frame and onclick function. On the leftIframe I have this:

```
<form action="predict_rightframe.php" method="post" name="form1" id="form1" target="rightIframe"><input type="checkbox" name="goalkeepers" value="1" onclick="this.form.submit(); window.location.reload(true)">
```

This works fine and super duper on Chrome. But when checking on Firefox and IE, the frame is opened in a new window.

Is there anyway around this?

I believe there is a "hack" whereby you can get javascript to create a frame. But there only advice I have found is how to create a hidden frame ([see here](http://terminalapp.net/submitting-a-form-with-target-set-to-a-script-generated-iframe-on-ie/)) But I want this frame to be visible.

Any help on this issue will be extremely helpful - even if its just adapting the above link's javascript code to create a visible iframe.

Comment: just a thought, but have you tried replacing `window.location.reload` to `location.reload`? That should imply the closest `window` object, IE the iFrame...

Comment: I will do. But the reload function is working fine on all browsers. It is the posting of the form bit which doesnt work - the result of the form opens in a new window rather than in the right Iframe.

Comment: Oh, then make sure you've set the `<base>` tag in the `<head>`

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes I already have the base tag in the head. Still no joy.

Comment: _crud_, I'll do some check in this after-lunch, if by then, you haven't gotten an answer yet. +1 for interesting case

Comment: Thanks. Have a look at that link in my question. I think that is the answer - it kind of tricks I.E.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this! This has taken up hours of my time.

But if anyone has the same problem. Here is the solution..

Create a file called frame.js with these details:

```
   var filePath = 'predict_rightframe.php';
// Setup the iframe target
var iframe='<iframe id="myIframe" name="myIframe" src ="predict_rightframe.php" width="300" height="450" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" frameborder="no" scrolling="no"></iframe>';
// Write the iframe to the page
document.write(iframe);

var myIframe = parent.document.getElementById("frame");
// Setup the width and height
myIframe.height = 450;
myIframe.width = 300;

myIframe.src = filePath;
// set the style of the iframe
myIframe.style.border = "0px solid #999";
myIframe.style.padding = "0px";
```

Then where you want the iframe to appear just put:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="includes/frame.js"></script>
```

I'm not overly sure why this works (frankly, I dont care cos it works!). It is something to do with IE not thinking an iframe is an object. Javascript can make IE think it is an object...well anyways now it works.